# python apply(zscore) problem ( i don't know why the value is NaN in the column)

Tags: python, indexing, z-score

heollo

i'm studying python through books.

in the book, there are the coding below.

i want to make a column named 'z-score'
but, it doesn't work.
(['z-score'] values are NaN)

```
data_bind = data_bind.dropna()
print(data_bind)
     code    name     CMP_CD    SEC_NM    return   rank
0    000020   donghwa  000020       health  0.023614  248.0
1    000040  motors  000040    economy -0.256716  627.0
2    000050     bang  000050    economy -0.288800  659.0
3    000070  samyang  000070      material  0.020528  256.0
4    000080  hite  000080   necessary -0.358872  713.0
......



data_bind['z-score'] = data_bind.groupby('SEC_NM', dropna=False)['return'].apply(zscore,   nan_policy='omit')


print(data_bind)
      code     SEC_NM      return    rank    z-score
0     000020     health    0.023614   248.0     NaN
1     000040     economy   -0.256716   627.0     NaN
.....

print(data_bind.groupby('SEC_NM', dropna=False)['return'].apply(zscore, nan_policy='omit'))

SEC_NM
health          [0.1436575842145283, -0.5022560341142324, 0.05...
economy          [0.4589118861712773, 1.4471044349054212, -0.43...
...
```

how i can resolve that?
give me some advice, please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.